# Angular 2 *ngFor performance issue with select/option

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm using `*ngFor` to populate `options` of `<select></select>`. My issue is that I can have `1000` array values for 1 of my 6 `<select>`. Performance is suffering. I know it's because of `changeDetection` or `One-way Binding`. Is there a way to better implement `*ngFor` for `<option>`. I don't actually need `change detection` or `one-way binding`.

**My Code**

```
<select [formControl]="requestForm.controls['SellCommodityId']">
   <option [value]="" disabled selected>COMMODITY/GRADE</option>
   <option [value]="item.Id" *ngFor="let item of fieldOptions?.Product;">{{item.Value}}</option>                
</select>
```

**UPDATE 12-20-2016**

I placed the select into it's one Component like this:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy,Input } from '@angular/core';
/**
 * <ihda-select [list]="list" [control]="control" [titleOption]="title"></ihda-select>
 */
@Component({
  selector:'ihda-select',
  changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template:`
    <select [formControl]="control" class="form-control">
       <option [value]="" disabled selected>{{titleOption}}</option>
       <option [value]="item.Id" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.Value}}</option>                
     </select>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
})
export class IHDASelect{
    @Input() list: any[];
    @Input() control: any;
    @Input() titleOption: string;
}
```

**Performance issue persisted.**

It seems like it wasn't the `changeDetection`, because i tried **removing the `[formControl]` attribute from the `<select>` and then there was no longer a performance issue.** It seems that using the `[formControl]` attribute here to track it for the form group causes the performance issue. Is there information about this? or how I may fix it?

### **UPDATE 12-21-2016**

Performance Issue shown in the plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/2jNKFotBRIIytcmLto7y?p=preview

If you click the **`Options Route`** it will take a long time to load the options. If you remove the form code the route doesn't take a long time to load.

Comment: Sounds like it might be worth a bug report (requires a Plunker that allows to reproduce)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer ok i'll try to reproduce the error in a plunkr

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added a plunker to show the behavior

Comment: How does the performance issue materialize? I don't know what the expected behavior is. When I navigate to options there is some delay (about 2 secs) I guess that might become faster with the built output and prodMode enabled. Have you tried? What browsers have you tried?

Comment: Just an idea. I tried to delay the rendering of the options to when select gets the focus. Also not perfect but also not too bad and it will be a lot faster in prodMode and AoT https://plnkr.co/edit/KRgYHktFXHyPugS3nPQk?p=preview
IE is the slowest, so testing there should show the worst case.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nice thinking on the delay until the select has focus

Comment: Not sure why you mention that. Is it because I added `OnPush`? I just exmperimented and forgot to remove it.

Comment: You could also use setTimeout to preload the arrays one after the other and not wait until they get focus to reduce the delay on focus. Kind of lazy pre-loading. It still would avoid the delay when navigating to the route because not all arrays are rendered at once.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm sorry. I meant, is the source of my performance issue that there are alot of values in the array? Does it have anything to do with [formControl] or ngFor?

Comment: I think it's just `*ngFor`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you want to post your approach for an answer?

Comment: Sure, if this works for you - done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the `Options` route is selected all `<options>` for all `<select>` are rendered in one go before the application responds again.

To avoid that the rendering of the `<options>` could be delayed so that they are only rendered on demand

```ts
<select [formControl]="control" class="form-control" (focus)="hasFocus = true">
   <option [value]="" disabled selected></option>
   <ng-container *ngIf="hasFocus">
     <option [value]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.value}}</option>                
   </ng-container>
</select>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/KRgYHktFXHyPugS3nPQk?p=preview

The strategy can be further optimized so that `hasFocus` is set to `true` delayed by a timer after the component is already shown for one `<select>` at a time, so that while the browser is idle it already renders the `<option>`s.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad to hear this solves your problem.

Comment: ok this fixed performance but another issue came with it. I have a button that I click to auto populate the fields with their proper values. when I click the button, it selects the appropriate value but the value is not seen in the select. Once I click the dropdown then it shows the value. The prepopulate was working before adding the focus, is there anything i can do to make this work?

Comment: In this case you need to set `hasFocus` before you assign the value or to make the component itself set `hasFocus = true` when a value is assigned. You might need to inject `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` after `hasFocus = true` to ensure the options are rendered before assigning the value.

Comment: could you add this function to the plunker? If possible it would be greatly appreciated? It didn't work for me so I may be missing something

Comment: Can you add what you explained in your previous comment, then I'll have a look to add my part.

Comment: You can see the [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QAyBOmgbF3QUZHUp8Ej4?p=preview) . I added a timeout to update hasFocus after a few seconds and a populate Fields button.

Comment: Where and how do you set the value? It's still about this problem right " I have a button that I click to auto populate the fields with their proper values. when I click the button, it selects the appropriate value but the value is not seen in the select."?

Comment: There is a method call populateFields() in the home component. If you click the button Populate fields it is called. Once you click the button, select one of the selects and you'll see the value set according to the method

Comment: Instead of passing a control to your custom component, the component should implement `ControlValueAccessor`, then just call `this.hasFocus = true; this.cdRef.detectChanges(); /*actually set the value*/; ` when the value is set. I don't think it makes sense to investigate with the current "weird" implementation. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/ControlValueAccessor-interface.html Sorry, I don't know a good example but there should be some blogs out how to do that.

Comment: Can I remove it from the custom component and place it in the HomeComponent and set the value there easiliy?

Comment: Remove what from the component? For what purpose? I don't get what you try to accomplish.

Comment: You see that I'm setting the value in the HomeComponent. Would it be easier if I placed all of the selects in the HomeComponent and just set the value their? Or is there another way to delay the array population while changing routes of the selects and then set their value? Could i have done this a better way?

Comment: I think wrapping it in a custom component is a good idea, but to make it work properly with reactive or template driven forms it should implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

Answer (score 0):

If your current component's change detection is not OnPUsh , you could wrap this select inside a component and make that ones to be OnPush and the pass the Product list to it to be used .

```
@Component({

  selector:'my-select',
  changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  inputs:['list','control'],
  template:`
    <select [formControl]="control">
       <option [value]="" disabled selected>COMMODITY/GRADE</option>
       <option [value]="item.Id" *ngFor="let item of list">{{item.Value}}</option>                
     </select>

  `
})

export class MySelectCompoent{

}
```

Then to use it :

```
   <my-select [control]='requestForm.controls['SellCommodityId']' [list]='fieldOptions?.Product'></my-select>
```

Then who ever is supplying the list , if want's to update it , should replace it.

Comment: So this will help performance because it will simply only print the values once and there will be no change detection on each option?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without creating a new component? Will my `FormGroup` still pick up the form controls upon submit?

Comment: Yes it does , you're isolating your select component and this is what angular2 all about ( components ) ,

Comment: Like I said , you could have changed the change detection of your current component and the result would be the same

Comment: I'm still having the performance issue, i'm going to post a fiddle